# Only move one page in double-page view | iBooks

Tags: software, books

I like reading books in double-page view in iBooks. But I always can only move two pages in this view, like in RL.
Is there a way to only move one page, for example to compare images on different pages and still keep the double-page view?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't look like there's a setting where you can make it go by one page, but what you can do is that you can use your Trackpad (the Magic Mouse works too) and move your fingers (to the left or right, depending on where the page are) so that you can see the pages that you want.

[image]
[image]

This may not be the most glamorous solution, but it gets the job done. Hope this helps.